# Symfony 4.3: Overwrite Command from other Bundle

Tags: symfony4

How can i overwrite in Symfony 4.3 a Command/bundleCommand.php from other bundle?

I tied to create a folder under src/Command/bundleCommand.php - but not working. Must i create also a folder with the bundle name in Command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your command as a [decorator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) in services.yaml. Try something like this:

```
services:

    App\Command\BundleCommand:
        decorates: Bundle\Command\BundleCommand
```